# Deleting lines with blank columns

Tags: regex, unix

I need to delete all lines from a file that are blank in column 2. For example if my file looked like this

> `1
>
>       2 2 
>       3
>
>       4 4`

I would need the output to be

```
2 2        
4 4
```

Also, the columns are tab delimited. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The formatting is off, never used this site before

Comment: That’s why there was a _preview_ provided under your “question”, before you “asked” it. Do you have any attempt of your own?

Comment: will the lines contain numbers only?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest simple **awk** solution:

```
awk 'NF>=2{ sub(/ */,""); print }' OFS='\t' file
```

The output:

```
2 2 
4 4
```